# Endless loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop

Beginner here.
Why is this an endless loop ?

```
for (p = 0; p < 5; p += 0.5)
{
    printf("p=%2.2f\n",p);
}
```

Comment: [Assuming `p` is `float` - it's not](http://ideone.com/7eet8).

Comment: this doesn't look like an endless loop to me

Comment: What is the type of `p`?

Comment: It depends on the type of `p`. Btw, comparing `float` or `double` using comparison operators is a bad idea.

Comment: @Tony The Lion :It prints an endless stream of 0's.p is float

Comment: In the future it would be nice if you'd post compilable code-samples that reproduce the problem. Not just an incomplete snippet, which might or might not reproduce the problem depending on how you fill in the blanks.

Comment: @user1190555 If p really were a float, the loop would terminate. [Proof](http://codepad.org/3bcYIz0J).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see an endless loop because your p is of an integral type (e.g. an `int`). No matter how many times you add `0.5` to an int, it would remain 0, because `int` truncates double/fp values assigned to it. In other words, it is equivalent to a loop where you add zero on each step.

If you make `p` a `float` or a `double`, your problem would go away.

**EDIT** (Suggested by Oli Charlesworth's comment)

It is worth noting that using floats and doubles to control loops is discouraged, because the results are not always as clean as in your example. Changing the step from `0.5` (which is 2 to the negative power of 1) to `0.1` (which is not an integral negative power of 2) would change the results that you see in a rather unexpected way.

If you need to iterate by a non-integer step, you should consider using this simple pattern:

```
// Loop is controlled by an integer counter
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    // FP value is calculated by multiplying the counter by the intended step:
    double p = i * 0.5;
    // p is between 0 and 4.5, inclusive
}
```

Comment: +1, indeed.  Though it's probably worth mentioning that using floating-point types for loop control is a bad idea, in general.  For instance, `for (double f = 0; f < 1; f+=0.1)` iterates 11 times, not 10.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks for a great point, I improved the answer to include it.

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on how `p` is declared. If it's an integer type, `p` will always be 0 (because the result of `0 + 0.5` will be truncated to 0 every time) so the `for` will never stop.

Answer (score 1):

a type conversion problem, float/double lost precision when assigned to an integer type.

P.S. It is really a very **bad idea** to use float/double in condition test. Not all floating point numbers in computers are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If `p` is a `float` or a `double`, there's nothing wrong with the code, and the loop will terminate.

If `p` is integer, the behaviour of the code is undefined since the format specifier in `printf()` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

when you add a double constant to integer variable, the double constant "becomes" integer. 0.5 becomes just 0. So you add 0 to p.

Comment: No, it's the other way round.  The variable is converted to a `double`, so the result is `0.5`.  But then this is assigned back to an integer, which results in truncation.